# Caching with GeoWeb Cache Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have around 1000 tiff files (each file around 300 MB in size), I published them via Geoserver as a mosaic using Image mosaic plugin; when trying to preview the published layer using openlayers, the layer performance is extremely slow at small scales (1:500000 and 1:1000000), and the server's CPU and memory are significantly consumed at these scales.
Accordingly, I am trying to cache this service using GeoWebcache that is shipped with Geoserver, I started the caching process using certain defined gridsets (2000000,1000000, 500000, 250000, 125000, 64000, 32000, 16000, 8000, 4000, 2000, 1000, 500). The problem is that the caching process has consumed all the space on my hard disk (e.g. the cache folder for 1:000 scale is larger than 400 GB) considering the fact that the whole mosaic size is less than 300 GB (with overviews).

The caching process is taking much much more space than the original data itself, so is this a normal behavior with GeoWebcache (I tried caching the same data at the same scales with ArcGIS server and it consumed less than 250 GB)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an [image pyramid store](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagepyramid.html) rather than a mosaic as otherwise (as you have found out) too many files are needed when a user views the whole area.

See the [GeoServer manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html) for details of how to install and set up a mosaic.

Comment: Thank Ian for the valuable input,
Do you have any suggestion about number of levels that I have to use in gdal_retile to view the raster at the scales mentioned above (considering that the resolution is 0.1 m)?